# iterating map of map in groovy

Tags: groovy, hashmap

I have a map of type
Map<Boolean,Map<String,String>>

how can i iterate over them. I have following code written but is there any better way to do it in groovy?

```
getTopic(boolean boo){
...
}

def test = { jsonMap ->
    jsonMap.each {
        def topic = it.getKey()
        it.getValue().each{
            println(topic+" "+" "+it.getKey()+" "+it.getValue())
        }
        println "Message sent for cluster " + it.getKey()
    }
}
```

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.plus() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [ ]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), split(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait(), any(), dump()
```

**update** :

```
def prod = new KafkaProducer([
        ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG       : "host",
        ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG  : "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
        ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG    : "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
        ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG                    : "all"
])
```

while creating this map i am getting

```
 Unexpected input: ':' @ line 15, column 55.
   OOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG       : "hos
```

what could be the reason?? i think i have created map properly.

Comment: which line is that?

Comment: Hi, just modified code snippet a bit. i am getting error on line println(topic+" "+" "+it.getKey()+" "+it.getValue())

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add seeminly unrelated further questions. Create a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not use implicit `it` variable in nested loops.
2. Do not use String concatenation in debug outputs, use GString interpolation instead.

I would start re-writing your code so:

```
def test = { jsonMap ->
    jsonMap.each{ topic, topicMap ->
        topicMap.each{
            println "$topic $it.key $it.value" // here it's ok to use "it"
        }
        println "Message sent for cluster $topic"
    }
}
```

Answer to **update**:

If you want to use constants as keys in Map literal, you have to put them in brackets `()`:

```
def prod = new KafkaProducer([
        (ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG)       : "host",
        (ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG)  : "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
])
```

Comment: i updated my question with one more problem i am facing. can you please tell me what is wrong with this map.